# Responsive issue at Mobile view and tab while using position: relative , absolute with property top and left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

im using the property position: relative,absolute,top and left
problem with Responsive on mobile view but working correctly on web page
im using two imgs  in one place which i show in img please check [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOlOs.jpg)

this one view pic but there is two pic which is place correctly but when i change to mobile view it show like

please check
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy2Hy.jpg)

im using this coded line

```html
<div style='position: relative;'>
<img src="images/frame tr.png"   style='width:750px;height:350px;' alt="png">
</div>
<nav class="navbar sticky-top" style='position:absolute;top:167px;left:97px'>
<div class="placeresult bg-light d-grid" style='width:153px;height:150px;' >
  <div class="form-group text-center wrapresult"  >
    <div class="resultholder">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $relative.qrcdr()>getConfig('placeholder'); ?>" />
  <div class="infopanel"></div>
  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="preloader">
     <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i></div>
     <input type="hidden" class="holdresult">
     <div class="text-center mt-2 linksholder"></div>
      </div>

  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove 100% width on image on mobile size. It is stretching the image